# apt-get update, dist-upgrade, autoremove, autoclean in a single sudo command

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

My usual command for keeping the machine up to date is rather verbose, and it can result in more than one password prompt if any command takes a long time:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I'd like to shorten this down to one command (preferably without using a global alias).

[Solution](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/d18a4d9be3cf17140bba242bca9f9923eaaf74bc/.bash_history#L1638) based on [@amra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3316818/96588) and [another tip](https://askubuntu.com/a/171/10371):

```
sudo sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade --yes && if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then echo You should reboot; fi'
```

Comment: try:
*sudo -s*
then use: *apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean; logout*

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get -y update;apt-get -y dist-upgrade;apt-get -y autoremove;apt-get -y autoclean"
```

Comment: Is there a common name people may assign to creating a custom mega-upgrade command like this? (I made up the name mega-upgrade ;)

Comment: I would call it: `alias apt-update-dist-upgrade-autoremove-autoclean='sudo sh -c "apt-get -y update;apt-get -y dist-upgrade;apt-get -y autoremove;apt-get -y autoclean"'`; But I would prefer only `apt-get upgrade` and decide myself when to `dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the '&&' operator to execute command 'cmd2' if and only if 'cmd1' has been executed without errors:

```
(cmd1 && cmd2)
```

But this only works in bash directly, without 'sudo' in front.

So, in order to work as expected, we can use the following command:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean"
```

Note that the answer proposed by amra does not the same as the above command:
Commands separated by ";" are executed in sequence without taking the exit code of the previous command into account.
When using "&&" to separate the commands, the exit code is taken into account.
Thus, if we have "cmd1 && cmd2", cmd2 is only executed if the exit code of cmd1 was 0 (i.e. cmd1 did not fail).